# start a transition event after loaded a image

Tags: javascript, css

I have a problem doing a transition, the div that contains the image should be going from "right: 200px;" to "400px" making the transition in 2s and the transition should start when the image is loaded in the document, here is the css code:

```
    div.contenedor {
        width: 300px;
        height: 257px;
        position: fixed;
        right: 200px;
        bottom: 0px;
        z-index: 100;
        -webkit-transition: right 2s;
        -moz-transition: right 2s;
        transition: right 2s;
    }
```

and here the js code:

```
        function transi() {
            var id = "L" + Math.floor(Math.random() * 10000);
            function open() {
                var eOpen = document.getElementById(id + "_container");
                    eOpen.style.right = "400px";
            };

            var dContenedor = document.createElement("div");
            dContenedor.id = id + "_container";
            dContenedor.className = "contenedor";

            var ima = document.createElement("img");
            ima.src = "XXXX.jpg";
            ima.width = "300";
            ima.height = "250";

            dContenedor.appendChild(ima);

            document.onreadystatechange = function(){
                var rsw = this.readyState;
                console.log(rsw);
                if (rsw) if (rsw != 'complete') if (rsw != 'loaded') {return;}
                document.body.appendChild(dContenedor);
                console.log(ima.complete);
                if (ima.complete) {
                    open();
                };
            }
        };
        transi();
```

For some reason is not making the transition, and the div is going direct to "400px", if someone have some ideas i would apreciate it, thank you in avance

Comment: it seems you've set the transition on an element, but what you're moving in your JS `open()` function is that element's container

Comment: `document.querySelector(<img element>).onload = function (){ ... }`

Comment: no, is the same element, dContenedor is the one that have the transition and when i call open() i search for that element "document.getElementById(id + "_container");" and change the "style.right" to 400.
yes, i did try with the onload, but with the same result.
i recently put the open() function inside of a "setTimeout()", like this, "setTimeout(function(){ open(); }, 3000);" and now the transition does appear, why?? i have not idea...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe call function on `load` event of image?

**UPD**
Added work example

```js
function transi() {
  var id = "L" + Math.floor(Math.random() * 10000);
  var dContenedor = document.createElement("div");
  dContenedor.id = id + "_container";
  dContenedor.className = "contenedor";

  function open() {
    // we already have ref to needed element
    dContenedor.style.right = "400px";
  };

  var ima = document.createElement("img");
  ima.width = "300";
  ima.height = "250";

  dContenedor.appendChild(ima);
  document.body.appendChild(dContenedor);
  // when image is loaded fire event
  ima.onload = function() {
    open();
  }
  ima.src = "https://v1.std3.ru/32/9b/1455811008-329b55c554efcec3988dc8ab44eb972f.jpeg";
};
transi();
```

```css
   div.contenedor {
     width: 300px;
     height: 257px;
     position: fixed;
     right: 200px;
     bottom: 0px;
     z-index: 100;
     -webkit-transition: right 2s;
     -moz-transition: right 2s;
     transition: right 2s;
     background: #333;
   }
```

Comment: i see why it did not work on my test page, i am put in the script on the <head> once i put it on the <body> work perfect, thanx @ThisMan